# How to prevent sub-objects from being deleted when deleting an object?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

Assume that the following `struct` is defined:

```
typedef struct A {
  int *b;
} A;

A* a = new A;
a->b = new int[100];
```

I thought that although I delete the object `a` by `delete a`, the object `b` in `a` must be dangled without being deleted.

However, it seems that accessing `b` (someone has pointer to point `b`) after deleting `a` causes segmentation fault.

Is this true?

If it is true, can it be prevented from being deleted by defining destructor of `struct A`?

Comment: The pointer `b` will be deleted with `a`, but what is pointed at by `b` won't be deleted by deleting `a` unless a destructor to delete that is defined for `A`.

Comment: Memory allocated and pointed to by `a->b` won't be deleted with your code, you just loose access to it, and will have a memory leak.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It seems that I missed something at somewhere in my code. Thank you.

Comment: It works exactly how you think it does. The int array is not deleted. Note that the pointer `b` is deleted, just not the array.

Comment: @MikeCAT -- the pointer `b` will be **destroyed** with `a`; it will not be **deleted**, because there's no `delete b;`.

Comment: Is `A` supposed to *own* (and hence `delete[]`) the `b` pointer, or is it a non-owning pointer?  There's always a hazard of a non-owning pointer being held in an object that the actual owner may invalidate the pointer.  For shared ownership, there is `std::shared_ptr`.  For codifying ownership, as well as managing, there's `std::unique_ptr`.  And consider if `std::vector` is a better container rather than a pointer to some sort of array.